# Required string 'contactID' parameter not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

This is my Controller:

student_details redirects you to a jsp file to view

```
@RequestMapping(params="render=student_details")
public String detailsRender(@RequestParam("contactId") String contactId, RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, Model model){
    String mdlContactId = request.getParameter("contactId");
    model.addAttribute("contactId", mdlContactId);
    return "student_details";
}
```

The for each loop in ajax code:

```
 result.data[index]["name"] = '<div class="pull-left">'+'<a href="'+$('#url-student-det').val()+ '&contactId=' + result.data[index]["contactId"] + '">'+result.data[index]["givenName"]+' '+result.data[index]["surname"]+'</a></div>';
```

Which gives this result below

[image]

As you can see string contactId is intact with the url.
When accessing the link. It still gives me the error

**Required String parameter 'contactId' is not present**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure this mapping is called?

Comment: yes. it returns me to the page student_details.

Comment: if you remove @RequestParam(contactId) is it will work??

Comment: Yes. Removing @RequestParam(contactId) works